# Bounds on entries of matrix inverse

Tags: matrices, upper-lower-bounds, positive-definite, matrix-norms

Suppose I have a positive semi-definite matrix **A** and a vector **x** with positive entries. I want to establish upper and lower bounds on the entries of the vector $(I+A)^{-1}x$. Using the $p_\infty$-norm I can get upper bounds on the absolute size of entries of $x$ using

$$\|(I+A)^{-1}x\|=\left(\min_{y≠0}\frac{\|(I+A)y\|}{\|y\|}\right)^{-1}\|x\|$$

However, I also need to get lower bounds for their absolute size. Is there a way to do this?

Finally, a question on signs: if $x$ is the 1-vector, is $(I+A)^{-1}1$ necessarily positive or can it be negative?

UPDATE: The answer to the last question is no.

Set $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    10 & 3 \\
    3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$. Then $(I+A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{13}
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -3 \\
    -3 & 11
\end{bmatrix}
$ whose first row sum is negative.

Comment: What is "the 1-vector"?

Comment: I mean, a vector of all ones $(1,1,1,...,1)^T$.

Comment: Why should what you wrote, $\|(I+A)^{-1}x\|=\|A\|^{-1}\|x\| $, be true?

Comment: Sorry, typo! I have corrected it. Also, note I didn't mean $||A^{-1}x||=||A||^{-1}||x||$, the maximum norm is replaced by a minimum inside the brackets.

Comment: Concerning your last question, you talk about positive definite matrix (meaning $(y,Ay)>0 $ for all $y$) but also positive vectors, presumably entrywise positive. I believe the answer is no but I don't have an explicit counter example now.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! I'm playing around with $e^T(I+A)^{-1}1=tr(e^T(I+A)^{-1}1)=tr((I+A)^{-1}1e^T)$ to see if it gets me anywhere.

Comment: I still don't see why the equality should be true. The min is the minimum singular value.

Comment: Assuming $e$ is a vector what you wrote is trivially true.

Comment: I'm using this post here for the equality: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432374/norm-of-matrix-inverse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110458/discussion-between-lcv-and-user1365680).